# Accurate time measurement in Linux

Tags: python, linux, time

I am collecting data from different sources and would like to get the time as accurate as possible.
Besides `timeit`, `time`. `monotonic`, `time.time`, is there something like a "realtime" method for Linux?

(I know, it depends from the operating system (open suse) and a multitasking/multiuser system will hardly be as accurate as a realtime system but to some extend i would like to take measure time as accurate as possible on a normal Linux system.)

example with time.time method. If i use this method in a loop where i install a sleep for 4 seconds (starting at second 8) , the measuments are:

```
absolute                distance to next measurement
8.040261268615723       0.01363372802734375     
12.053894996643066      0.012626409530639648    
16.066521406173706      0.020114421844482422    
20.08663582801819
```

where i have a certain start time and an execution time for the loop which is about 20ms because the distance from one measurent to the next is about 0.02 second.

Addendum: the time measurement for time.monotonic is nearly the same as the above (time.time).

Code piece for the loop:

```
seconds = 4
MAX = 11

     for i in range (1,MAX+1):
        sleep (seconds)                                    # 
        mt1.tick()                                          # take time stamp
        Ergebnis.append(mt1.elapsed_time)                   # get absolute time
        Differenz.append(mt1.elapsed_time - i*Sekunden)     # get elapsed time difference (compared to ideal time)
```

Comment: What would you be measuring, exactly?

Comment: It depends. Normaly data collected from devices but that would be not such important. The base question is which method of measuring time is the best or which is nearly realtime) because the execution of code in python and call for example of system services also takes time.

Comment: If you want real time (like something that truly represents "2020-09-14 17:05"), `time.time()` (or `time.time_ns()`) is as accurate as you can get.

Comment: Your example doesn't measure the accuracy of `time.time()` – it measures how long it takes for Python to execute everything else between your `time.sleep()`s.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. You can install a hardware GPS-based clock on a system to provide highly accurate (sub-ms jitter) wallclock time, which is great for things like "at what time did I receive this data", but that won't have any impact on the variable timing of process context switches.

Comment: That is what i said. "How long it takes" is the time between two events.

Comment: Well, you _are_ measuring the time between two events, it just takes a little more than the sleep duration you expect.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I´ve already installed GPS devices (in the past) and took the time. But then i have, additionally to that, the execution time of the code which is collecting the data. And that execution time is shown above. The divergence of the system clock within for example 4 seconds is, compared to "real" time collecting from GPS, in that time span, very low.

Comment: @AKX: yes, thats right. And the difference is the execution time of the code (inclusive system call, context switches, paging, swapping, etc...)

Comment: @Coliban Yep, but I'm (or we're) still not sure what it is exactly that you'd want. A more accurate `sleep()`? Even a C program, which should be fast to execute, (https://gist.github.com/akx/81733fe0a5bda30203891bd87b90cb2d) has a "drift" of 120 to 5000 microseconds per a second's sleep on my Macbook.

Comment: @AKX: as mrentioned: getting the most accurate time which is possible on such a system. And, as you can see, the drift is smaller than 20 milliseconds between the sleep periods. (I post the loop above)

Comment: Again, if you want the most accurate real-world wallclock time, `time.time()` or `time.time_ns()`. Yes, calling it takes time, but there's nothing you can do about that unless you have another even more accurate clock to calibrate against.

Comment: Use [`clock_gettime_ns`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock_gettime_ns) with [`CLOCK_MONOTONIC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.CLOCK_MONOTONIC). Och, there it is, use `time.monotonic_ns()` to be portable

Comment: Ok, i will try it.

Comment: @KamilCuk CLOCK_MONOTONIC "represents monotonic time since some unspecified starting point" – in case OP wants to actually capture a wallclock time, that may not be a good choice.

Comment: @AKX,  i have several signal sources and i would like to capture the time between several event as acurate as possible. I could get the wallclock time with a gps-device or ntp but that would not be such important. The elapsed time between several events eg. between a stimulation and the events would be important and there  "time.monotonic()" should work as well. I have to make tests between the different measurement methods.

Comment: How do you access the signal sources? Would it be possible to have them report a timestamp instead of you needing to measure it separately? Do they push data, or does your real code actually sleep for some time, then check whether there's something to read, then sleep some more?

Answer (score 2):

I have made some measurements and searched threw answers about timing questions and came to some sort of (for me) important conclusions. Many, high voted answers, mentioned that the selection of adequate timing functions would provide best response times, for example time.monotonic (oder monotonic_ns) or timeit.default_timer() (because there, the python interpreter would choose the most adequate and accurate measurement) or time.time().
First i will show the test situation for clarification. But this is not as important as the base question, which timing method would generate the most accurate time. I only show it for a better understanding and because there was a question for it.
[image]

I made tests with three timing methods, time.monotonic(), timeit.default_timer() and time.time(). While timeit.default_timer() seamed to be the most accurate timer, the difference to the others where not that impressive for me. Then i though about multiuser/multiprocessing and priorities of processes and the scheduling in a multiuser-system. The scheduler in open suse is distributing process time just like any other multiuser system and the scheduling depends on the priority of the process. I looked at my default process priority, it is by default 19. I changed the priority as an parameter and made my tests again and the response time is indeed depending on the process priority and it seems as if there is a hard limes, it is on my system "0": it seems that all processes about process priority "0" are scheduled on an slow lane. In contrast, all process with an lower(higher) priority than 0 are getting processor time faster. In the loop above i avoided system calls which would slow the process down, i collected the data to calculate the results behind the loop.
The data is showing that the absolute delay 1) depends on the process priority and 2) that the absolute delay of the different methods differ significantly only at process priorities above 0. Under 0 it seems regardless which method i choose.
The absolute delay for processing one loop is more than 20ms above process priority of 0 and around 4ms beneath that priority. The rise of the slope is due to the repeated processing of the loop and the summation of every pass.

With this result i can roughly estimate the timings for my measurements and, in my case, when the measurement time is significant above some seconds (in my case about 30) the accuracy of about 4 ms is more than sufficient. More than that, because it seems that the response time beneath process priority 0 is predictable (and not as stochastic as above 0) i can calculate the delay into my measurements because the response time seems linear (and correlate) to the number of instructions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good science here :) Did you try whether this is also true with other significant load on your system (if that may be a scenario that happens in your real situation)?

Comment: Hello AKX, thanks, occasionally it stopped all unnecessary applications, but that didnt made a huge difference. Thy seem to differ a little in priorities above 0, but that could be only randomly. Priorities under 0 are nearly the same. If applications are set to higher priorities, they "naturally" would get less process time or faster response. The target system will be dedicated only to the controller, if i wanted to top response time i have to investigate some real time systems. (Don´t know now if that would be worth the effort).